# Converting POST request from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I have this php script that uploads an mp3 file to a website on the user's behalf. It works well but I want to write it in python:

```
$id = $argv[1];
$file = $argv[2];
$course = $argv[3];
$audio_column_number = $argv[4];



if( !file_exists( $file ) ) {
    die();
}

$curlFile = new CURLFile( $argv[2] );
$curlFile->setPostFilename( basename( $argv[2] ) );
$curlFile->setMimeType( "audio/mpeg" );

$post = array(
    'thing_id'  => $id,
    'cell_id'   => $audio_column_number,
    'cell_type' => 'column',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken'   => '2N829n66bh5Alhbc463wYtoqpyosyON',
    'f' => $curlFile,
);

$curl = curl_init( "http://www.memrise.com/ajax/thing/cell/upload_file/" );
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => $course,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0",
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => "Cookie:__uvt=; __utmt=6; csrftoken=2N829n66bh5Alhbc463wYtoqpyosyON; sessionid=zj8suxtx841zlwrn10o6x3suzdjw9wpt; __utma=216705802.691983187.1416840006.1429942996.1430039373.8; __utmb=216705802.4.10.1440411307; __utmc=216705802; __utmz=216705802.1416840006.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); uvts=2Mnc8QsWzuuv8GVh",
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
) );
$res = curl_exec( $curl );
```

I'm trying to convert it to python. That seems simple enough, I though. Here's what I tried:

```
import requests
import sys

files = {'f': ('f.mp3', open(sys.argv[2], 'rb'), 'audio/mp3')}
form_data = { 
    "thing_id": sys.argv[1], 
    "cell_id": sys.argv[4], 
    "cell_type": "column",
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "2N829n66bh5Alhbc463wYtoqpyosyON"}
cookies = {
    "__uvt":"",
    "__utmt":"6",
    "csrftoken":"2N829n66bh5Alhbc463wYtoqpyosyON",
    "sessionid":"zj8suxtx841zlwrn10o6x3suzdjw9wpt",
    "__utma":"216705802.691983187.1416840006.1429942996.1430039373.8",
    "__utmb":"216705802.4.10.1440411307",
    "__utmc":"216705802",
    "__utmz":"216705802.1416840006.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)",
    "uvts":"2Mnc8QsWzuuv8GVh"}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0",
    "referer": sys.argv[3]}
url = "http://www.memrise.com/ajax/thing/cell/upload_file/"

r = requests.post(url, files=files, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, timeout=60)
print(r.text)
```

Against what I expected, while the php script works perfectly, the equivalent python code does not. The server rejects it and sends a 403. I don't have a lot of experience with PHP but I've given a solid effort in trying to understand the PHP script. I'm wondering if anybody can find what the PHP script is doing that the Python script is failing to. If it helps, I used is Chrome's developer tools to see an example of what the post request is doing in the website when I upload a file there:

headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,en-CA;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:4271
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=---- WebKitFormBoundarytv2Kbmk1kUAGBVZ1
Cookie:i18next=en; sessionid=xrxg3zofonxmfmfvoe38gv56mgdefa71; fbm_143688012353890=base_domain=.www.memrise.com; csrftoken=MxIto89I10jvWe45lt5xBJ8xnQkWayh3; fbsr_143688012353890=YBKZYHGnLaxApGPYElgXzoLMgGpF10HWFPMjE4jAq60.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; _sp_id.7bc7=06d67edb75b91041.1466936153.142.1469853985.1469803261
Host:www.memrise.com
Origin:http://www.memrise.com
Referer:http://www.memrise.com/course/1160304/idioms-and-sentences/edit/database/2129600/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
```

Request Payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarytv2Kbmk1kUAGBVZ1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="thing_id"

112172106
------WebKitFormBoundarytv2Kbmk1kUAGBVZ1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cell_id"

4
------WebKitFormBoundarytv2Kbmk1kUAGBVZ1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cell_type"

column
------WebKitFormBoundarytv2Kbmk1kUAGBVZ1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"

MxIto89I10jvWe45lt5xBJ8xnQkWayh3
------WebKitFormBoundarytv2Kbmk1kUAGBVZ1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f"; filename="f.mp3"
Content-Type: audio/mp3


------WebKitFormBoundarytv2Kbmk1kUAGBVZ1--
```

Please keep in mind that I changed the cookies somewhat to protect my account on the other website.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why is `$post` so different then `form_data`  I don't know python but seems like the post data should be similar?

Comment: the good syntax in useragent should be "User-Agent". The server may be rejecting the request due to this incorrect syntax.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I suspect the reason is that I'm using the requests library. This advertises itself as "http requests for humans" and does a lot of the heavy lifting by itself.

Comment: @Artemis Looking at the information seen making the same request through the website and monitoring it with Chrome's developer tools, I found that you're right, that was part of the problem. After fixing it, I still have my problem. Of course, thank you for finding that.

Comment: @DrewSSP - I was specifically talking about the naming of the post parameters, not the way the HTTP request is made,  In php you are posting this key `thing_id`, and in Python that is no where that I see it.  In the Python form data `id` is using `argv[1]` and same with `thing_id` in php `argv[1]`, I have no idea if it's equivalent, just an observation.

Comment: Additionally `cell_id` and `cell_type` seem to be AWOL in the Python...  Obviously I have no idea what any of that is, just I would assume that if you are posting data to an external Application, that you would need to post the same data just with a different language.  Not a different set of data.  `Request Payload:` is from which one, PHP or Python?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix That was actually an oversight of mine when copying things to SO. Sorry for that and thanks for pointing it out. I made the edit here in the question. The problem persists.

Request Payload is from chrome when I upload the file through the user interface of the website. I spied on the headers that were sent using Chrome's network tab in the Inspect Element area

Comment: Still doesnt answer it, is it when running the request in PHP or Python,  PHP I would guess.  Your file mime type is different too, but it's probably not the issue.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix It's neither of the two scripts. This website is typically accessed through Chrome. By opening Chrome's Developer Tools and clicking on the Network Tab, one can see the headers, cookies, form data, etc... My script is supposed to simulate the request that is normally sent by the browser when a user uploads a file. With the Network tab open in Developer Tools, I uploaded a file as a user and was shown the post request that went along with it. The above headers and Request Payload are from that. That is, essentially, what I am trying to emulate with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. While many variables were declared, not all of them were being properly used. This problem was solved by changing `requests.post(url, files=files, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, timeout=60)` 
to `requests.post(url, files=files, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, form=form_data, timeout=60)`